# Django CeateView and change recodrs in other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 models and during add record to database i want change one field in other model

```
class Room2Create(CreateView):
    model = Room2
    form_class = Room2Form
    template_name = 'room2_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        q = Room1.objects.filter(id__startswith=self.object.room_status)
        q.room_status = self.object.room_status
        for elem in q:
            elem.save()
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Can you help me ?
What is wrong ?

Comment: That query looks very strange. Are you sure you mean the *id* starts with the room status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the `id__startswith` query but it looks you're not modifing the objects while iterating over the Room1 instances in the queryset.

You don't need the `commit=False` either, cause you're not changing the *Room2* instance after the form `save` method.

```
class Room2Create(CreateView):
    model = Room2
    form_class = Room2Form
    template_name = 'room2_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        q = Room1.objects.filter(id__startswith=self.object.room_status)
        for elem in q:
            elem.room_status = self.object.room_status
            elem.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

That said if your business logic requires a change to *Room1* status when *Room2* get saved, it'll be more appropriate to move that logic into the `save` method of the *Room2Form* or into the `save` methdo of the Room2 model, depending on your needs.

Comment: you are right. i change startswith to exact and copy elem.room_status = self.object.room_status to inside for loop, and now all is ok. thanks